# How to run a system command in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to make gnuplot scripts to output *.eps files and change them into .pdf type automatically. I have a test demo which goes as:

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set output "SystemCommand.eps"

plot sin(x)

set xl "x"

set yl "y=sin(x)"

system(sprintf("epstopdf %s",SystemCommand.eps))
```

but it doesn't produce what I want, an error comes out every time that says:

```
"SystemCommand.gp", line 6: undefined variable: SystemCommand
```

I have tried to use SystemCommand or SystemCommand.eps, no difference here. Anyone has a suggestion?
I use Ubuntu 14.04 and bash shell.

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the filename in `sprintf`.

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set output "SystemCommand.eps"

plot sin(x)

set xl "x"

set yl "y=sin(x)"

system(sprintf("epstopdf %s","SystemCommand.eps"))
```

Comment: Thank you. That really works. In addition, I found appending [link] '!epstopdf SystemCommand.eps' to the plot script also produces a pdf file. I don't know the difference but just offer another choice.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that. But I am new here it said I don't have enough reputation.>_<. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: `!command` is the same as `system(command)`. Furthermore, there is no need for sprintf, as you can just join two strings:  `system("epstopdf "."SystemCommand.eps")`